# How to parse これは、動詞や形容詞のように文の中での使われ方によって形が変化する言葉の、他の形の用法と対立する、最も機能の多い形につけられた名前です?

Tags: parsing

> それから、「基本形」という用語について。**これは、動詞や形容詞のように文の中での使われ方によって形が変化する言葉の、他の形の用法と対立する、最も機能の多い形につけられた名前です**。動詞や形容詞の形の変化と（これを「活用」と呼びます）その使われ方については、「21．活用・活用形」で述べます。動詞とイ形容詞の基本形は、辞書に使われているので「辞書形」と呼ばれることも多いです。ただし、ナ形容詞だけは基本形から「だ」をとった形が辞書に載せられています。

I'm not really sure how I should break up that long sentence, the use of commas are also really giving me a hard time.

I first tried breaking it up like this,

> 動詞や形容詞のように文の中での使われ方によって形が変化する言葉**の** - Words that, just like 動詞 and 形容詞, changes form/shape depending (conjugates I assume) on how it's used in a sentence. **の**?

From there, I am a bit confused. What's the use of の after 言葉 - what is it connected with? Can someone break it down for me?

[Source](http://niwanoda.web.fc2.com/bunpou/00hajimeni.html)

Comment: Damn that's a wordy way to explain 基本形 lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand correctly the part up to the の, which connects with 形.

The overall structure is これは [[...言葉の] [[他の形...多い]形]] につけられた名前です. So the translation would be something along the lines of

> This is the name given to the form that ＜他の形の..対立する＞ and ＜最も機能の多い＞ of those words that, just like 動詞 and 形容詞 ＜...＞ ,

where your translation suffices for ＜....＞.

A confusing part may be both 他の形の...対立する and 最も機能の多い both modifies 形.

---

I'm not exactly sure what 他の形の用法と対立する means. Probably something like *distinct from usage of other forms*.